# Win32 API working with arrays

Tags: c, arrays

I'm beginner of programmer. I not understande why can't copy some script from array to another one.

```
char array1[11];
char array2[2];
array1 = {'255 105 85'};
array2[0] = array1[0];
array2[1] = array1[1];
array2[2] = array1[2];

MessageBox(hwnd,array2,"mes",NULL);
```

I was get "5" instead of "255".
I using the code::blocks with GCC complier.The project created with win32 frame based.
Somebody has idea what cause the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following construct is not allowed in C:

```
array1 = {'255 105 85'};
```

Instead you might consider using the static array initialization like this:

```
char array1[11] = {255, 105, 85};
```

This will fill the array1 with 3 specified values and leave all the other elements set to 0 (i.e. elements starting with index 3 and ending with index 10).

It's rather surprising, why the compiler didn't issue a syntax error in your case

**updated:**
Please also note that you are manipulating with individual characters when you have an expression like this array1[2]. If you want to operate on strings (i.e. have 3 separate strings for the numbers you have specified), you will have to declare something like this:

```
   char *array1[3] = {
         "255",
         "105",
         "85"
   };

   char *array2[3];

   array2[0] = array1[0];
   array2[1] = array1[1];
   array2[2] = array1[2];
```

Thus you will have an array of strings. Each entry of array1 will contain a pointer (address) of the memory where string "255" is located (please note that "255" is an array comprising 4 chars: '2', '5', '5', '\0').

Answer (score 0):

Array1 should be declared like this:

`char array1[] = {0x255, 0x105, 0x85};`

single quotes are for single chars in ascii, like `'a'` or `'6'` or `'!'`.

Also, array2 is of length 2, but you are assigning a value to the third value (`array2[2]`). This is probably an error.